# Is there a way to count the number of times a audio button is being clicked and save that to database using ajax call?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, audio

I am trying to make a audio player which counts  the number of times the audio is being played daily and stores the data in the database to display it on real time basis .

I am planning to use audio tag , and jquery to interact with that for the purpose of storing data into the database

Comment: There a so many way to do it

Comment: call a simple php script  that increase the number in the database, if you have already a php script you can pu it there,  javascript can do it also without php

Answer (score 2):

```
const audio= document.querySelector('audio');

audio.onplay = (event) => {
  $.get(`/capture/play/audio/${event.id}`);
};
```

Or

```
$('audio').on("play", function(){
 $.get(`/capture/play/audio/${this.id}`);
}
```

On the server-side, you can save the session id of the request to help you prevent increasing your play count in the cause the user pauses and returns to play the audio after pausing.

Comment: I have tried the second method of yours , and the click button is sending atleast 100 requests per click of the audio button , what can be done to prevent it to only one